# Testing Python script that generates files with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-unittest

I have a series of Python scripts for which I am finally building unittests. The scripts generally read a bunch of Excel files, do some processing in pandas, and then generate one or more output files.

The scripts generally look like this:

```
import datetime
import paths # contains common pathlib.Path objects for all scripts
NOW = datetime.datetime.now()

INPUT_DATA = pd.read_excel(paths.data_filepath, ...)

def main():
   ... do a bunch of stuff with INPUT_DATA to get MUNGED_DATA
   report_path = paths.output_dir / f"report {NOW:%Y-%m-%d %I:%M}.xlsx"
   with pd.ExcelFile(report_path) as fp:
       MUNGED_DATA.to_excel(fp)
```

Sometimes I generate two files with one script.

In the testing script, I import the script as a module and force the data I want to test by overriding the imported module's global variables, but I don't know how to capture the output. It seems risky to generate the output files and delete them again. Is there any way to capture files generated through `pandas.to_excel`  and `pandas.to_csv` for testing purposes?

```
import datetime
import pathlib
import paths # my predetermined path library

mock_dir = pathlib.Path(".").absolute() / "mocks"
paths.data_filepath = mock_dir / "mockdata.xlsx" # this is a stub file to speed up testing

import data_processing_script as script

script.NOW =datetime.datetime(1999,12, 31, 23, 59, 59) # ensures all output files have same name

class TestTheScript(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_intended_success(self):
        script.INPUTDATA = pd.DataFrame( ... mock data ... )
        script.main()
        intended = pd.Series( ... items I expect ...)
        result = pd.read_excel('mocks/report 1999-12-31.xlsx')
        self.assertEqual(set(intended, set(result[Target Column Name]))

        # there is only one column in the established dataset worth testing in this case, and the order of the items do not matter
```

As soon as I run two tests, I get a Permission error because the output file is still "open" or is being copied by OneDrive (I think this is the case because when I pause OneDrive the tests all pass without giving me the permissions error). Since I'm not going to remember to stop OneDrive from messing with me, is there a better way to capture these files in the testing environment?

Comment: You could run the tests in a fake filesystem by using [pyfakefs](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs) - this would avoid writing real files and the problems with OneDrive.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Unfortunately I get consistent permission errors with pyfakefs when the main script attempts to write the file.

Comment: That may be due to some stuff loaded before patching started, or you didn't add your mock files to the fake filesystem - both could be handled, but an easier solution without the need for pykafefs is preferrable, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get `pyfakefs` to work and no other solution seems immediately forthcoming, so I edited my script to look like this:

```
import datetime
import paths # contains common pathlib.Path objects for all scripts
NOW = datetime.datetime.now()

INPUT_DATA = pd.read_excel(paths.data_filepath, ...)

def munge():
   ... do a bunch of stuff with INPUT_DATA to get MUNGED_DATA
   return MUNGED_DATA

def main():
   MUNGED_DATA = munge()
   report_path = paths.output_dir / f"report {NOW:%Y-%m-%d %I:%M}.xlsx"
   with pd.ExcelFile(report_path) as fp:
       MUNGED_DATA.to_excel(fp)
```

And then updated the tests to call munge instead

```
class TestTheScript(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_intended_success(self):
        script.INPUTDATA = pd.DataFrame( ... mock data ... )
        result = script.munge()
        intended = pd.Series( ... items I expect ...)
        
        self.assertEqual(set(intended), set(result[Target Column Name]))
```

Now my tests work without having to worry about the file system.